# How to run command asynchronously whith :lua command?

Tags: lua

When using vim8.1, it does not provide `vim.fn` and `vim.call` function, so we can not use `vim.fn.job_start`. then how can I run command asynchronously in lua?

Comment: `vim.eval()` should be still there. If you find it inconvenient then consider upgrading your Vim.

Comment: @Matt Thanks, but I do not think `vim.eval` supports run command asynchronously.